# SwiftUI ScrollView vertical and horizontal scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-list, swiftui

I have a scrollview that i want change the orientation of the scroll based on a @State.

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State var isVertical: Boolean = true

    var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button(action: {
                self.isVertical.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("press me")
        }.padding()
        ScrollView(self.isVertical == true ? .horizontal : .vertical, showsIndicators: true){
                    if(self.isVertical){
                        HStack {
                            Text("a")
                            Text("b")
                            Text("c")
                            Text("d")

                            Spacer()
                        }
                    } else {
                        VStack{
                            Text("a")
                            Text("b")
                            Text("c")
                            Text("d")
                        }
                    }
                }.padding()
    }
}
```

When within the first time on this screen the scrollview is vertical, as soon as I click on the button and invert the state, the scrollview changes and goes crazy, scrolls both vertically and horizontally. What am I doing wrong? I would like that based on one you are scroll scrolling either vertically or horizontally. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fixed variant (also corrected handling of `isVertical` to align with meaning)

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State var isVertical: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                    self.isVertical.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("press me")
            }.padding()
            ScrollView(self.isVertical ? .vertical : .horizontal, showsIndicators: true){
                        if(self.isVertical){
                            VStack {
                                Text("a")
                                Text("b")
                                Text("c")
                                Text("d")

                                Spacer()
                            }
                        } else {
                            HStack{
                                Text("a")
                                Text("b")
                                Text("c")
                                Text("d")
                            }
                        }
                    }.id(isVertical)       // << main part !!
                     .padding()
        }
    }
}
```